# Java determine if it is running in Eclipse or Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, filenotfoundexception

I have a line that opens a text file:

```
File file = new File("src/roster.txt");
```

and it causes trouble because in the Eclipse environment it runs fine, but in the terminal when I do

```
javac Program.java
```

it throws the `FileNotFoundException`. My temporary solution is:

```
if (file.exists() && file.isFile()){ // true if running in Eclipse
    ....
}
else{
    file = new File("roster.txt");
    ...
}
```

Which works fine. But is there a way to detect what environment the program is running on? Thank you.

Comment: IMO that's the wrong approach. Instead provide a mechanism to locate a file properly regardless of the runtime environment. If you don't actually need it to be an arbitrary file then package it up and read it as a resource.

Comment: I want to read it as a resource but the requirements require it to be located in src

Comment: If you want to read it as a resource why are you reading it as a file?